# After their rise to power in 1932, were any of the elections or referenda under the Nazis legitimate?

Tags: nazi-germany

Such as the 1933 election, Rhineland referendumm or Anschluss. Such as, were they free (secret ballot, no  punishment for voting against what the Nazis wanted) or fair (as in the results reflect the ballots cast,with no electoral fraud)

Comment: Define "legitimate"? Referenda, such as that which preceded the anschluss, were conducted in a climate of fear and intimidation. You could argue similarly for the 1933 election too.

Answer (score 2):

The Machtergreifung was in [1933](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nazi_seizure_of_power), not 1932.

The [1933 election](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_federal_election,_March_1933) was the last one where multiple parties could run, but even so it did not come close to democratic standards. The Nazi party thugs were openly present in the polling stations.

Look at the published results of the [1936 election](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_election_and_referendum,_1936), for instance, or the [ballot](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Wahlzettel-3.-Reich.jpg). Not democratic at all.